# Get an address for place ID in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, google-places-api, geocode

am new to flutter

Am working on a project that uses places API and Google map.
I want the users to be able to get a place address when they input the place id.

I have been able to retrieve the place id using geocode.

Please how to I get the place address using the place id

Comment: What is the package your are using, can you share a link please?

Comment: geolocator and google search_map_places

Comment: i just want to do what was done here [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-place-id)  in flutter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [google_maps_webservice](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_webservice) package:

```
final geocoding = GoogleMapsGeocoding(
      apiKey: '...........');

final response = await geocoding.searchByPlaceId('ChIJd8BlQ2BZwokRAFUEcm_qrcA');

final result =  response.results[0].formattedAddress;
// Result will be: 277 Bedford Ave, Brooklyn, NY 11211, USA
```

Remember to enable the service from the Developer Console.

Comment: I am glad it helped. Could you please do me a favor and mark this question answered.

Answer (score 1):

You can read all information about Place IDs from the official doc:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/place-id

Just make a GET request:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?place_id=ChIJrTLr-GyuEmsRBfy61i59si0&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

Comment: this is a good solution though.

Comment: it gives xmlhttprequest error cors issue is there any solution about it

Comment: This won't work on flutter web. As the API is not meant to use on the web. It gives CORS errors.